# system crashed during update from 11.10 to 12.4 64bits

Tags: upgrade

system crashed during update from 11.10 to 12.4 64 bits

i had to hard reset due to inactivity during the update, after rebooting, ubuntu started, but it doesn't let me to enter Terminal, it only react when i search something in unity, but it doesn't let me to access any window, nor Terminal nor update manager, nothing, it appears that the cursor is in the center of the screen (as it reacts as i press ctrl, but that's all, i've tried pressing ctrl+tab but doesn't work either, i can access to anything but unity btton searches).

Comment: Dell LATITUDE E5500 64bits

Comment: And what's the question? I only see statements.

Comment: sorry, the question is:

Is there a way to restore the system?
to avoid format?
to upgrade or downgrade?

i've tried using older version from the grub but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

if you can boot into a terminal /ctrl/alt/F1 log in with your username and password then try sudo apt-get -f install [fix broken packages]  or sudo apt-get update[update packages [sudo apt-get upgrade]upgrades packages dpkg--configure-a[try to fix broken packages,